# How to write these symbols in Latex?

Tags: symbols

I need to write a few symbols in LaTeX:

[image]

but I do not know how can this be done and I cannot do a Google search because I do not know their names.

Comment: Try `$\mathcal{A}$`, `$\mathcal{R}$`.

Comment: Use [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) to find a symbol that you don't know the name of. It didn't spot the `A` or the `R` but it did spot that you can get this style using the command given by Corentin. It also says that you need to load `\usepackage{amssymb}` for `\mathcal`.

Comment: @AbdulhaqElhouderi -- actually, `\mathcal` is a "basic" math alphabet, and doesn't need `amssymb`.  (perhaps you're thinking of `\mathbb` which *does* need `amssymb`.)